# How can I put N's in my final string

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I'm beginner in perl so im have some problems writing a script.
I want a script that put the letter N one certain number of times with basis in a length that I previous check. This Ns have to be in the final of a string inside a .txt. This strings begin with a `>` and have that 'face':

`A1_23ABR2014_53_CC07.P10R_E07_009.ab1`

```
attgccttttgctagcttatagaataataattcatataaacaaaaaatat
tttatattatttaaaaataaataaaccaaataaagtcattgttgatccaa
ttgaacaaatcatattccatccatttaaagcgtctggataatcaggaata
cgtctaggcattacattaaatccaagaaaatgcataggtaagaatgttaa
```

I already wrote that, but I don't know how to do next.

```
if $qend > $sendi{
    my $leg1 = $qendi - $sendi;
    open(my @final, '>>', 'contiggeral.fasta') or die;
    while (N < $leg1) {
    do N++ in @nomecontig
}
```

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition if non-modifier `if` must be enclosed in parentheses. Variables must start with a sigil (N has none). There is no `in` operator in Perl.

```
my $string = 'abc';
my $final_length = 20;
$string .= 'N' x ($final_length - length $string);
print $string, "\n";
```